# No insertar datos duplicados

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x

estoy un poco confuso, cual seria la mejor practica para no insertar datos duplicados en una tabla, tengo el siguiente código.

```
cnn = pyodbc.connect ( 'Driver={SQL Server};Server=**;Database=**;uid=**;pwd=**',autocommit=True )


sqlcmd = ("Select GEOM.STX as lng,GEOM.STY as lat,a.Codigo from Cie a \
                       inner join Inmueble b on a.idInmueble = b.idInmueble \
                       inner join DiviPolitica c on c.idDiviPolitica = b.idDiviPolitica \
                       inner join Dire d on d.idDivisionPolitica = c.idDivisionPolitica where d.geom is not null")

    read = fiona.open(r"\\geo-pre\data\ViasActivos.shp")        

    base = cnn.cursor()
    base.execute(sqlcmd)

                for feature in read:
                    coord = feature['geometry']['coordinates'][0]
                    name = feature['properties']['Name']
                    linea = feature['properties']['LINEA']
                    ramal = feature['properties']['RAMAL']
                    cabecera = feature['properties']['CABECERAS']

                    for r in base:
                        longVias = coord[0]
                        latVias = coord[1]

                        cordenadas = '\''+str(longVias)+','+str(latVias)+'\''

                        center_point = [{'lat': latCIE, 'lng': lngCIE}]
                        test_point = [{'lat': latVias, 'lng': longVias}]

                        lat1 = center_point[0]['lat']
                        lon1 = center_point[0]['lng']
                        lat2 = test_point[0]['lat']
                        lon2 = test_point[0]['lng']

                        radius = 5.00 # radio en kilometros

                        a = haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2)

                        insertVia = ("INSERT INTO [dbo].[atributosCapas] \
                                                                  (idCapaOrigen,[idTipo] \
                                                                  ,[idOrigen] \
                                                                  ,[GeomTipo] \
                                                                  ,[Geom] \
                                                                  ,[Fecha] \
                                                                  ,[Nombre] \
                                                                  ,[Direccion] \
                                                                  ,[Localidad] \
                                                                  ,[Provincia],descripcion,cadena)\
                                        VALUES (null,3,2,'Punto',null,GETDATE(),'%s',null,null,null,null,'Ramal:%s,Linea:%s,cabecera:%s','%s')" % \
                                 (name,ramal,linea,cabecera,cordenadas))

                        base.execute(insertVia)
```

El primer **for** recorre un shapefile, el segundo **for** recorre una consulta MSSQL que posterior insertar en una tabla, ahora bien el unico campo que tengo para preguntar si ese dato ya existe en la tabla [dbo].[atributosCapas] es por el nombre(name), cual seria la mejor practica para no insertar duplicados

Edit: Agrego a la pregunta que quisiera evitar tecnicas como NOT IN o EXIST

Answer (score 1):

Lo mejor en ese caso es dejar la integridad de los datos al motor, de forma tal que desde cualquier aplicación se cumpla con esa restricción de no duplicar valores -evitar redundancia-

Si la tabla existe entonces le haces un alter:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MiTabla ADD CONSTRAINT
    IX_nombres UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
    (
    Nombre
    ) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

El unique te hace el trabajo... En caso que estés creando la tabla de cero, lo incluyes justo después de la columna:

```
create table nombres (Id int identity, Nombre varchar(10) unique)
```

Comment: Si, pero en este caso el programa fallara y se detendra la ejecucion, necesitaría que descarte los duplicados y continué ejecutandose

Comment: Entonces es inevitable que valides el valor de la variable antes de intentar hacer el insert.